# ASP.NET Code Delimiters return blank on load

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, data-binding

I have a GridView with a TemplateField column that has an asp:Button in the ItemTemplate. The text of the button is `<%# Bind("Active") %>` while the datasource selectcommand is

> "SELECT col1, col2, col3, CASE WHEN [Active] = 'true' THEN 'Active'
>   ELSE 'Inactive' END AS [Active] FROM table

I want to change the CssClass of the button to one thing when the text says "Active" and set the CssClass to something else when it says "Inactive". Yet when I debug the GridView registers "" for the Cell on load. Right now my IF check is in the RowDataBound event. Does it need to be in a different event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

added the code in the RowDataBound event rather than switching the value of CssClass

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a single ' after Active

Comment: Sure am. I have it correctly in my code, but as soon as I figure out how to edit my question I will fix it to avoid further confusion. Thank you for pointing this out.

Comment: my breakpoint doesn't even stop the debugger when I put it on the DataBinding event.

Comment: Yessir. VS scaffolded a method when I first added a databound method. After that didn't work I changed the code to "Handles gvMain.DataBinding" rather than "Handles gvMain.DataBound"